# how reference storyboard (current view) from another normal class

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift

I would like to create an animation in a class (outside of my normal view) called from `viewDidLoad` method and make it run on the storyboard :

How do I connect the class effect with the class `ViewController` (storyboard) ??

```
class ViewController : UIViewController
   {
       var effetto:Effects = Effects()

       override func viewDidLoad()
      {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           effects.typeEffects = 1
           effects.createEffect
      }
   }

   class Effects {

       var squareView: UIView!
       var gravity: UIGravityBehavior!
       var animator: UIDynamicAnimator!
       var collision: UICollisionBehavior!

       var typeEffects = 0

       func createEffect()
       {
          If var typeEffect = 1){
             gravity()
          } else {
             other()
          }
       }

       func gravity()
       {
        squareView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        squareView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        viewController.addSubview(squareView)

        animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: viewControlle)
        gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [squareView])
        animator.addBehavior(gravity)

        collision = UICollisionBehavior(items: [squareView])
        collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true
        // collision.addBoundaryWithIdentifier("barrier", fromPoint:  CGPointMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 350), toPoint: CGPointMake(self.view.frame.origin.x + self.view.frame.width, 350))
        animator.addBehavior(collision)
       }
       func other()
       {
         ......
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you dont hook your non-subclass object to anything in the storyboard. Your UIViewController's class name is non-descriptive but it would still work and contains an instance of the Effects class. On viewDidLoad you are creating an instance of that class. Just type in ViewController for the class name in the identity inspector in IB. Otherwise name it more descriptive such as the following then add EffectsViewController in the identity inspector if it's confusing. Something like the following should work(not tested and is shown purely to show object passing)

```
class EffectsViewController : UIViewController
   {
       var effects:Effects = Effects()

       override func viewDidLoad()
      {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           effects.effectsViewController = self
           effects.typeEffects = 1
           effects.createEffect
      }
   }

   class Effects {
       var effectsViewController: EffectsViewController!
       var squareView: UIView!
       var gravity: UIGravityBehavior!
       var animator: UIDynamicAnimator!
       var collision: UICollisionBehavior!

       var typeEffects = 0

       func createEffect()
       {
          If var typeEffect = 1){
             gravity()
          } else {
             other()
          }
       }

       func gravity()
       {
        squareView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        squareView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        effectsViewController.addSubview(squareView)

        animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: viewControlle)
        gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [squareView])
        animator.addBehavior(gravity)

        collision = UICollisionBehavior(items: [squareView])
        collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true
        // collision.addBoundaryWithIdentifier("barrier", fromPoint:  CGPointMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 350), toPoint: CGPointMake(self.view.frame.origin.x + self.view.frame.width, 350))
        animator.addBehavior(collision)
       }
       func other()
       {
         ......
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pick the ViewController in the storyboard. Then go to the identity inspector on the right pane. The top option is to select the class.